# npm reports "requires (one version)' but will load (another version)"

Tags: node.js, npm

Likely after cordove install with `npm` I got warning messages almost for every npm operations "requires colors@'>=0.6.0' but will load .. color"

```
D:\Workspaces\Enide-Studio-2014\OpenWith.js>npm i . -g
C:\Users\weibl\AppData\Roaming\npm\openwith -> C:\Users\weibl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\openwith\bin\openwith.js
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\weibl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\cordova requires colors@'>=0.6.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\weibl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\colors,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.6.0-1
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\weibl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\node-static requires colors@'>=0.6.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\weibl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\colors,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.6.0-1
openwith@0.11.0 C:\Users\weibl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\openwith
```

How to fix such npm errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrew hinted, solution was to

```
npm -g update colors
```

Comment: I keep getting this after an update, any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Clean out the node-Modules folder and re-run:
    npm install

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Not here to argue. I had the same error and simple updating wouldn't fix it.  Deleting the contents of node_modules and doing npm install worked.

Answer (score 0):

**At first,** delete the `phonegap\` folder in the location `C:\Users\weibl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\`. Of course, specific location will be different for others.

**Then**, proceed for any `npm` install/update command you want.